# another CSS height 100% problem

Tags: html, css, height

UPDATE: I think there was too many information. Here's my question: how to make the height of #middle 100% of the remaining space in the following exampl:

```
<body>
    <div id="big">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div id="btm"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

height of #big, body, html is all 100%.
Height of header and bottom are 120px;

Comment: From the FAQ: "If your question is about ... **Web design and HTML/CSS layout,** and your job title is "designer", ask on [Doctype](http://doctype.com/)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Changed my example to match your updated question

Here's a working example of your layout. Tested in IE8, IE7, Firefox, and Chrome.

The key here is NOT to set this height of `middle` to 100%. Instead, you position it absolutely, with `top` and `bottom` equal to the height of your `header` and `btm` elements (in your case, 120px).

If you set the height of the `middle` element to 100%, it will be the same height as the `big` element, which is 100% of the body tag, and hence your `middle` element will be too large, causing horizontal scroll bars.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #big
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #header
        {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #DDD;
            height: 120px;
        }
        #btm
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 120px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: #999;
        }
        #middle
        {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 120px;
            bottom: 120px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="big">
        <div id="header">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
            middle
        </div>
        <div id="btm">
            bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```